# cp after xargs not working

Tags: cp, xargs

I run debian jessie on Host 64-bit and in virtualbox 32-bit. To spare traffic I try to cp the i386 packages from host to the shared folder, for using them in virualbox.

```
My Hostname/var/cache/apt/archives$ ls -al /var/cache/apt/archives/ |
    grep 'i386' | 
    awk '{print $9}'
alsa-oss_1.0.28-1_i386.deb
gcc-4.9-base_4.9.2-10_i386.deb
i965-va-driver_1.4.1-2_i386.deb
libaacplus2_2.0.2-dmo2_i386.deb
libaio1_0.3.110-1_i386.deb
libasound2_1.0.28-1_i386.deb
libasound2-dev_1.0.28-1_i386.deb
libasound2-plugins_1.0.28-1+b1_i386.deb
```

Shows me the packages I'm looking for. but them I try to **cp** them after **xargs**

```
My Hostname/var/cache/apt/archives$ ls -al /var/cache/apt/archives/ |
    grep 'i386' |
    awk '{print $9}' |
    LANG=C xargs cp -u /home/alex/debian-share/apt-archives/
cp: target 'zlib1g_1%3a1.2.8.dfsg-2+b1_i386.deb' is not a directory
```

I can not figure out what I am doing wrong. Is this way even possible?

My problem is I can not script. Probable it is somthing like that

```
for i in *_i386.deb ; do cp [option] full-path to shared-folder
```

I didn't dry, because I will not mess my Host.

Comment: I think you meant to use `cp -t` instead of `cp -u` ?

Comment: No I mean -u `-u, --update                 copy only when the SOURCE file is newer
                                 than the destination file or when the
                                 destination file is missing`

Comment: also, whole thing can be simplified I feel.. something like `cp -ut /home/alex/debian-share/apt-archives/ /var/cache/apt/archives/*i386*` .. please try this on some other sample directories

Comment: That works. I'm thinkinng sometimes to complicated. ^^ Make your comment to an answer, so I can except this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
ls -al /var/cache/apt/archives/ |
    grep 'i386' | 
    awk '{print $9}'
```

can be simplified to `/var/cache/apt/archives/*i386*`

So, use either of these two:

```
cp -u /var/cache/apt/archives/*i386* /home/alex/debian-share/apt-archives/

cp -ut /home/alex/debian-share/apt-archives/ /var/cache/apt/archives/*i386*
```

where

```
   -t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY
          copy all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY
```

See also [info on parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 61):

While you already know how you should solve your current problem, I'll still answer about `xargs`.

`xargs` puts the string it got in the end of command, while in your case you need that string before the last argument of `cp`. Use `-I` option of `xargs` to construct the command. Like this:

```
ls /source/path/*pattern* | xargs -I{} cp -u {} /destination/path
```

In this example I'm using `{}` to as a replacement string, so the syntax looks similar to `find`.

Comment: is the {} arbitrary? could I do -Iblah for example?

Comment: Yes, you could.

Comment: on mac without -u